# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

when I try to import keras on a Jupyter notebook I receive this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.

I need to use keras to build an LSTM model fora project and am a beginner in python so I don't know how to get around this error. I have tried to install tenserflow and keras into an environment on anaconda but I receive the same error. For reference, I am using a Mac.

My code:

```
#Import libraries used
import math
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to import keras models and layers from tensorflow: from tensorflow.keras.models ...

Comment: use `pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cell at the beginning containing,

```
 !pip install tensorflow
```

and run it before running to other cells